# Div Slideshow with dynamic display time

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, duration, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to display a slideshow of divs, but the display time of each divs should vary.
The display time should be controlled with a data-attribute (duration).
I tried this with "setTimeout" but I'm getting the error: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" and it will stop at the third slide.
Here's my code:

```js
var active = document.querySelector('#cycler .active');

function changeTime() {
    t = active.dataset.duration * 1000;
}

function cycleDivs() {
    active = document.querySelector('#cycler .active');
    var next = (active.nextElementSibling) ? active.nextElementSibling : document.querySelector('#cycler div:first-child');

    function swapDivs() {
        active.classList.remove('active');
        next.classList.add('active');
    }
    swapDivs();
    changeTime();
    setTimeout(cycleDivs(), t);
}
changeTime();
setTimeout(cycleDivs(), t);
```

```css
#cycler :not(.active) {
        display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="cycler">
    <div class="slide active" data-duration="6">6</div>
    <div class="slide" data-duration="6">1</div>
    <div class="slide" data-duration="6">2</div>
    <div class="slide" data-duration="6">3</div>
    <div class="slide" data-duration="6">4</div>
    <div class="slide" data-duration="6">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think setTimeout requires a reference to the function, like `setTimeout(cycleDivs,t);` to work as intended.